# Spring Loaded Potentiometer?

Tags: components

Y'all will have to forgive my ignorance of electrical components, but what is the name of the electrical component that acts like a rotary potentiometer but when you release it, it pops back to 12 o'clock.

It can go both clockwise and counterclockwise from the 12 o'clock position to control a motor forwards and backward and then return to 12 upon release.

Comment: I don't know if there is an "official" term for it, but you can try searching for: self centering potentiometer.

Comment: Joystick? (perhaps 1 axis joystick)?

Comment: Seems like an old telephone mechanism.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers That generated switched pulses and only went one way from the rest position.

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks ... I didn't know that, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device you are looking for is a [spring return potentiometer](http://www.precisionsales.com/potentiometers/singleturn/spring-return.htm)